# Local Groups and Users in Administors groups

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Would require a couple of reports for security audit on users and groups for Windows 2003 and 2008 servers. The script will be run locally on the server.

1. **Administrators Group report**

   This are list of members part of local administrators group and should contain the below column headers. This should list only the group name and not users part of the group.

   ```
   Server Name, Local or Domain, Domain, USER ID, Account/Group
   abc, domain, abc.com, xyz, Account
   def, domain, abc.com, pqr, groupname
   ```
2. **Local Users report**.

   This is a local users reports and should contain the below column headers.

   ```
   USER ID, Account Disabled, Full Name, Last Login details
   User1, No, User Name, <date time>
   User2, Yes, Full Name, <date time>
   ```

**Stuff I tried:**

1. `net local users` and `net local group` → I am unable to fetch the other users properties.
2. `get-wmiobject win32_useraccount` → Unable to get the group info.

Answer (score 0):

1. Something like this might do:

   ```
   $hostname = $(hostname)
   $isLocal = @{
     $true  = "local";
     $false = "domain";
   }
   $type = @{
     "Win32_UserAccount" = "User";
     "Win32_Group"       = "Group";
   }

   gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Group.Domain='$hostname',Name='Administrators'} WHERE assocClass=Win32_GroupUser" |
     select @{n="Server Name";e={$hostname}},
       @{n="Local or Domain";e={$isLocal[$($_.Domain -eq $hostname)]}},
       Domain, Name, @{n="Account/Group";e={$type[$_.__CLASS]}} |
     ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
   ```

   Untested, though, since I don't have an AD at hand.
2. Local user information can be retrieved like this:

   ```
   $sys = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
   $sys.Children | ? { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} |
     select @{n="USER ID";e={$_.Name.Value}},
            @{n="Account Disabled";e={[bool]($_.UserFlags.Value -band 2)}},
            @{n="Full Name";e={$_.FullName.Value}},
            @{n="Last Login Details";e={$_.LastLogin.Value}} |
     ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
   ```

Comment: 1. This is taking ages to complete. Is it because its expanding the whole users part of the group.  
2. Sorry for the that; I have changed it.

Comment: Did you run the code as-is? How long exactly is "ages"? How many members does your administrators group have?

Comment: I ran as it is and there were 20 members part of the administrators group. I waited for more than 45mins and still was taking time. I interrupted mid way.

Comment: Try splitting the pipeline into several steps and use `Measure-Command` on each step to determine which one is slow.